# Passing variables into callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have a piece of code like this:

```
var guid = 'unique_guid';
con.query('SELECT guid FROM myDB.myTable WHERE guid = ?', guid, function(err, rows) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(rows.length == 0) {
        console.log('new guid: ' + guid);
        // do more things which require guid
    } else {
        console.log('old guid: ' + guid);
        // do more things which require guid
    }
}
```

In order to avoid callback hell, I give the call back function a name and refactor it as the following:

```
var checkExistence = function(err, rows) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(rows.length == 0) {
        console.log('new guid: ' + guid);       // guid can't be referenced here
        // do more things which require guid
    } else {
        console.log('old guid: ' + guid);       // guid can't be referenced here
        // do more things which require guid
    }
}
con.query('SELECT guid FROM myDB.myTable WHERE guid = ?', guid, checkExistence);
```

`con` is a connection created from [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)

Now my problem is that I can't reference guid in `checkExistence()`, and I don't want to make `guid` as a global variable.

Is it possible to get `guid` in `checkExistence()`?

Comment: Callback will be  `function(){ checkExistence(guid); }` and accept `guid`  as argument..

Comment: Why not just add a parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add guid as parameter and return a function:

```
var checkExistence = function(guid) {
    return function(err, rows) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(rows.length == 0) {
            console.log('new guid: ' + guid);       // guid can't be referenced here
            // do more things which require guid
        } else {
            console.log('old guid: ' + guid);       // guid can't be referenced here
            // do more things which require guid
        }
    };
};
con.query('SELECT guid FROM myDB.myTable WHERE guid = ?', guid, checkExistence(guid));
```

Comment: Thank you :-). I'm new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Function.bind function for thet, like this:

```
var checkExistence = function(guid, err, rows) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(rows.length == 0) {
        console.log('new guid: ' + guid);       // guid can't be referenced here
        // do more things which require guid
    } else {
        console.log('old guid: ' + guid);       // guid can't be referenced here
        // do more things which require guid
    }
}
con.query('SELECT guid FROM myDB.myTable WHERE guid = ?', guid, checkExistence.bind(null, guid));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the bind function,

```
var checkExistence = function(guid, err, rows) { ...
```

and call the method query like this

```
con.query('SELECT guid FROM myDB.myTable WHERE guid = ?', guid, checkExistence.bind(null, guid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var checkExistence = function(err, rows, guid) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(rows.length == 0) {
        console.log('new guid: ' + guid);       // guid can't be referenced here
        // do more things which require guid
    } else {
        console.log('old guid: ' + guid);       // guid can't be referenced here
        // do more things which require guid
    }
}
con.query('SELECT guid FROM myDB.myTable WHERE guid = ?', guid, checkExistence(err, rows, guid));
```